# how to make 1111 into 1 in python

Tags: python, algorithm, binary, scalar

i want to make function to make from `1111 into 1 and 0000 into 0`.

for the example:

```
Input:
['1111', '1111', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '0000']

Desired output:
11011010010000000100110000101100
```

But i don't know how to make it or the algorithm. Can you help me?

My attempt so far:

```py
def bagiskalar(biner):
    print(biner)
    biner = str(biner)
    n = 4
    hasil = []
    potong = [biner[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(biner), n)]
    for a in potong:
        hasil = potong.append(a)
    
    return hasil
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use list comprehension and the `join()` method:

```
lst = ['1111', '1111', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '0000']
s = ''.join(['1' if x == '1111' else '0' for x in lst ])
print(s)
# prints 11011010010000000100110000101100
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input is well-formatted, i.e. you don't expect other values than 1111 or 0000, you can optimize by taking only the first character.

```py
output = "".join([x[0] for x in input])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have pre-populated dictionary.

```
mapper = {'1111': '1', '0000': '0'}  # can be extended for other maps if needed

input_data = ['1111', '1111', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '1111', '0000', '1111', '1111', '0000', '0000']

output_data = ''.join([mapper.get(item) for item in input_data])
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like school assignment, so I'll make simple example. I assume, you really want to append result only from exact '0000' and '1111', and ignore other strings.

```
def bagiskalar(biner):
    result = ""
    for b in biner:
        if b == '0000' or b == '1111':
            result = result + b[0]
    return result
```

It just goes through your list of strings, checks each one of the that is it either '0000' or '1111'. And if it is, then add the first character ('0' or '1') to the result string.